# Alinhar duas divs verticalmente depois de usar float em uma delas

Tags: css

Estou criando um rodapé para uma página html. Ele é bem simples e composto por uma ÚNICA linha. Gostaria de que uma parte, que contém as informações de Copy, ficasse alinhada à margem esquerda e outra, que contém um menu, ficasse alinhada à margem direita do site.

Separei o texto em duas `divs` e dei um `float: right` na segunda. Acontece que não estou conseguindo alinhar as duas partes verticalmente de modo que pareçam estar na mesma linha.

Seguem os códigos:

**HTML**

```
<section id="rodape-legal">
    <div class="rodape-legal" id="rodape-legal-copy">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2017. Todos os direitos reservados.</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="rodape-legal" id="rodape-legal-menu">
        <nav class="doc-legais">
        <h1>Documentos Legais</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Início</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Blog</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Facebook</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Twitter</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Linkedin</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Segurança</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Privacidade</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Termos de uso</a></h6></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section#rodape-legal {
margin: auto;
padding-top: -20px;
text-align: left;
}

div.rodape-legal {
display: inline-block;
}

div#rodape-legal-menu {
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}

nav.doc-legais li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
}

nav.doc-legais h1 {
display: none;
}

nav.doc-legais a {
transition: color, 1s;
text-decoration: none;
color: black
}

footer h6 {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De `margin: 0` na tag `ul`. As `ul` vem por padrão nos navegadores com `margin`, assim como as tags mais utilizadas `p` e `h`. E também com a chegada do `-webkit` está vindo com `-webkit-padding-start`, que da `padding` da esquerda para a direita, como se fosse um `padding-left`.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa retirar a `margin` da `<ul>` dentro da `div` da direita:

```
div#rodape-legal-menu ul {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Essa `margin` nativa da `<ul>` está criando um espaço vertical na `div`.

Precisa também definir um `line-height` do mesmo tamanho da fonte, para ajustar a linha:

```
nav.doc-legais {
   line-height: 12px;
}
```

**Execute o snippet abaixo em tela cheia para ver o resultado:**

```css
section#rodape-legal {
margin: auto;
padding-top: -20px;
text-align: left;
}

div.rodape-legal {
display: inline-block;
}

nav.doc-legais {
   line-height: 12px;
}

div#rodape-legal-menu ul {
   margin: 0;
}

div#rodape-legal-menu {
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}

nav.doc-legais li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
}

nav.doc-legais h1 {
display: none;
}

nav.doc-legais a {
transition: color, 1s;
text-decoration: none;
color: black
}

footer h6 {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<section id="rodape-legal">
    <div class="rodape-legal" id="rodape-legal-copy">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2017. Todos os direitos reservados.</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="rodape-legal" id="rodape-legal-menu">
        <nav class="doc-legais">
        <h1>Documentos Legais</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Início</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Blog</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Facebook</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Twitter</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Linkedin</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Segurança</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Privacidade</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Termos de uso</a></h6></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

### EDIT

Para ficar responsivo, eu sugeria definir `width: 50%;` em cada `div` e mais outros ajustes:

```css
section#rodape-legal {
margin: auto;
padding-top: -20px;
text-align: left;
display: block;
}

div.rodape-legal {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
}

div.rodape-legal ul,
div.rodape-legal li,
div.rodape-legal h6 {
   margin: 0;
}

div#rodape-legal-menu {
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}

nav.doc-legais li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
}

nav.doc-legais {
   line-height: 12px;
}

nav.doc-legais h1 {
display: none;
}

nav.doc-legais a {
transition: color, 1s;
text-decoration: none;
color: black
}

footer h6 {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<section id="rodape-legal">
    <div class="rodape-legal" id="rodape-legal-copy">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2017. Todos os direitos reservados.</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="rodape-legal" id="rodape-legal-menu">
        <nav class="doc-legais">
        <h1>Documentos Legais</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Início</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Blog</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Facebook</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Twitter</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Linkedin</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Segurança</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Privacidade</a></h6></li>
                <li class="menu"><h6><a href="#">Termos de uso</a></h6></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```